# How do you install the Vulkan validation layers on Windows?

Tags: vulkan

I am following the instructions on the Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers github:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/layers/README.md

I've built the layers, copied the DLLs next to my executable (for test purposes, will setup the path later), created a vk_layer_settings.txt (also alongside my executable), and set the layer names in my VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS env. var.

But no matter what I do the array returned by vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties does not contain any validation layers.

What magic step have I missed? This is Windows 8.1 running on a Nvidia 970M

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the DLLs, the loader also needs to find the appropriate layer manifest json files.

Easiest way is to just set the `VK_LAYER_PATH` environment variable to the release build output folder of the validation layer project you cloned from github like this:

`VK_LAYER_PATH=X:\YOUR-PATH-HERE\build\layers\Release`

The loader will then load the validation layers form that folder, and you'll always be using the most recent layer version.

Comment: Though while I get the individual layers ('VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation', 'VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker', 'VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation') I don't see VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation (that layer "contains" the other ones right?). Is that correct? (the example I am following requests  VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation) Is there an extra step I need to do to see that?

Comment: ```VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation``` is a meta-layer that just stores the list of all the other layers in the right order. It's not a physical layer like the others and as such doesn't come with a json or dll.

Comment: Starting with SDK 49, there is now a VkLayer_standard_validation.json file that leverages new "meta-layer" support in the layer json files to define the list of layers that make up the standard validation layer.  Previously the standard validation layer was "hard-defined" inside the loader.